# Cant connect to my VPS from Ubuntu Terminal

Tags: 14.04, command-line, server, ssh

im try connect to my server using ubuntu terminal

```
ssh -p 2222 -i mypublickey.ppk username@ip
```

then its ask
"Enter passphrase for key 'mypublickey.ppk':"

Im entering my password but its always wrong then i got error
Permission denide (publickey).

i have no problem if connect from Putty ubuntu or windows

Comment: `.ppk` files are usually PuTTY keys, which are not generally understood by other SSH implementations. If your VPS is using OpenSSH then you will need to convert the ppk file to OpenSSH format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the PPK key to openssh format. It is quite simple even on Ubuntu:

- Install putty tools: `sudo apt-get install putty-tools`
- Convert `puttygen mypublickey.ppk -O private-openssh -o mypublickey`