# SSH connection on Amazon AWS

Tags: networking, ssh, amazon-ec2

this is my first serious question, so, try and be easy on me.

I'm trying to SSH to a EC2 instance on Amazon AWS, and recently it stopped working out of nowhere, the SSH was working fine until it started returning this error:

```
ssh -i ~/Downloads/ead.ppk root@--.---.---.-- -v
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to --.---.---.-- [--.---.---.--] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ruggi/Downloads/ead.ppk type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ruggi/Downloads/ead.ppk-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

I try to access from a different computer that is not in my local LAN and it works through putty.

I already tried through putty, I added the private key normally, same error, tried Filezzilla through SFTP, still same error, is there something I can do to fix this?

And I am connecting to a real ip, not --.---.---.-- .

Comment: maybe you should check the permissions of the folder where the keys are stored..  + It means that there is no such file or directory that ssh wanted to access...!!

Comment: You should move your .ppk file to ~/.ssh.  Most likely the permissions on ~/Downloads are too open.

Comment: Moved the ppk to ~/.ssh/ead.ppk still same errors whan me to change the question with the verbose?

Comment: Make sure ~/.ssh is not writeable by any other user, same with the ppk.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cant connect to my VPS from Ubuntu Terminal](http://askubuntu.com/questions/726616/cant-connect-to-my-vps-from-ubuntu-terminal)

Comment: It already is a public key, as the possible duplicate suggests it is not a putty key, I can't connect either through the command line, or putty, or fillezilla.

Comment: And if I connect with a computer from outside my company LAN I have no access problems.